# How do I read this frequency response chart?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, frequency-response, flat

I'm looking for a directional (off-axis rejection) microphone with flat frequency response. The Shure SM81 is the only such mic that I've been able to find online, however its frequency response chart has multiple lines and I don't know what that means?

From [Shure SM81 spec sheet pdf](https://www.shure.com.cn/dmsfiles/default/shure/products/microphones/user_guides/sm/sm81_specsheet)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response curves are for each of the three selectable roll-off switch positions...

- Flat [image]
- –6 dB/octave below 100 Hz [image]
- –18 dB/octave below 80 Hz [image]

From the spec sheet -

**Low Frequency Response Switch Positions**
Flat; –6 dB/octave below 100 Hz; –18 dB/octave below 80 Hz